# Embedded hyperlinks to URL's in Word open in IE Compatibility mode

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, internet-explorer-11

In Word and Excel 2010, we have noticed that embedded hyperlinks to web locations open in IE 7 Compatibility mode tabs (we are using IE 11). That is causing a problem for what we are trying to do. Have investigated this behavior to no avail. My question is -

Is there a way to force websites opened from Word/Excel hyperlinks to open in standard, non-compatibility mode IE instances/tabs?

Comment: Is it doing this for a link to _any_ site (ie: www.googlecom), or just specific site(s) (say, your internal Intranet)?

Answer (score 0):

If the targets of your hyperlinks are being loaded from the local file system, an internal network, or some other Intranet site, they're likely being loaded into compatibility view as a result of the default settings.

You can change this by changing the local compatibility view settings.  For a full walkthrough of the steps for individual machines, see this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272454/ie11-document-mode-defaults-to-ie7-how-to-reset/27278277#27278277).  To apply similar changes across your organization, use [group policy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2013/10/23/how-to-add-web-site-to-compatibility-view-list-via-gpo.aspx).

Hope this helps...

-- Lance